# MySQL query error with a table named "order"

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this problem but I just found out the solution so I'll write it here anyway in case anyone stumbles in it.
This is my mysql query:

`mysql_query("SELECT id FROM order ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1")`

And the error I received was

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1' at line 1

Comment: The reason behind the problem was that my table "order" was confused with the order command in sql query, so the solution was to wrap it like this:

    mysql_query("SELECT id FROM `order` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Order** is reserved Word. You have to use like Enclose ORDER in back-ticks.

Try this

```
mysql_query("SELECT id FROM `order` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1")
```

**[Reserved Words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)**